# Convert mysql query (if function) to db2

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I have a query which works fine in mysql but I need to migrate it to db2.

Here is mysql query:

```
SELECT
    message, host, location
FROM
    table
WHERE 
    host = 'VALUE_HOST' OR location = 'VALUE_LOCATION')
OR
    (message IS NOT NULL AND host IS NULL AND location IS NULL)
ORDER BY
    (IF(message IS NOT NULL,1,0)*8 + IF(host = 'VALUE_HOST',1,0)*4 + IF(location = 'VALUE_LOCATION',1,0)*2) DESC
```

The point is how to replace if function in "order by" part that I get the same sorted result based on these conditions?

Comment: please elaborate your question and add table data for reference

Answer (score 1):

DB2 does not have the IF function, but it has the CASE expression:

```
CASE WHEN message IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

or, if you simply test for equality:

```
CASE host WHEN 'VALUE_HOST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```